# google sheets function/script for adding specific cells adjacent cell value to another cells value

Tags: google-sheets

So for reference, I'm trying to create a sort of JRPG sheet for these way more elaborate than need be sorts of roleplaying sessions I tend to do. I wanted to make my job easier having to pay attention to things by making a skills sheet this go around on the stats. So you use a special skill or magic and it takes MP or what have you [current mp/max mp and the box it pulls the current mp from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trC9o.png) and then we have the hypothetical skills sheet [skills, a "use" area for telling it the skills been used, and then the amount itd add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG4kk.png) I have 0 coding knowledge but I basically want it to be able to work on every skill and onward. so just simple "activate from use cell, pull adjacent right value, and add it to energy used" -5 would then be -15 from simply using first skill.
Note that the energy used cell will never change, while the use cell and cost cell do.

i have 0 knowledge of how to code. i struggle to wrap my head around it. idk the language or what to look for. all i know is that it needs to be some elaborate form of cell's adjacent value added to separate cell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Use" column is in column A, "Cost" column in column B, and "Energy Used" column in column C. The formula would be:

`=IF(A2="Used", B2, 0)`

Drag this formula down to apply it to multiple rows. It checks if a skill is used; if yes, it adds the cost to "Energy Used"; otherwise, it adds 0.